# if screen resolution is less than x append css

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to modify the css of an element if the screen resolution is less than 960px

my code isn't working, not seeing any errors in firebug.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
    jQuery(".snow").css('display', 'none');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra?

Comment: you can do this with media queries but are you seeing the display none getting attached on the element once below 960? Also are you sure your browser size is below 960?

Comment: are you calling from within $(function(){})  ?

Comment: Are you sure you included the jQuery library properly? Your code should work.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can do this entirely with CSS using the `@media` command.

```
@media (max-width:960px) { css... } //nothing with screen size bigger than 960px

@media (min-width:960px) { css... } //nothing with screen size smaller than 960px
```

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Jason Whitted makes a good point, this is CSS 3 only, so it won't work with older browsers (it should work with all modern browsers though). See [here](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) for compatibility. Your main problems will be IE 8 and less.

**Edit - device selection**

```
@media screen { .nomobile { display: block; } } //desktops/laptops

@media handheld { .nomobile { display: none; } } //mobile devices
```

Or you could assume mobile devices will have a smaller width, and go on that.

Comment: This does require a CSS3 compliant browser, but this is an ideal solution.

Comment: please note if you are doing some kind of a fluid responsive website, the js width and media query width are different due to scrollbar. You might need to sync it if needed

Comment: I should have said I need it for a responsive site, I need to hide the div on mobile & tablet devices, will @media work still?

Comment: yes as long as your responsiveness is based on the width of the browser only. In the project i am working on now, we also have body classes which identify if the user is viewing on a phone/tablet, but we still base our main css to the width. So even if you are on desktop and you resize to phone size you will see the phone version of the site

Comment: just tried @media and works perfect plus I've learned something new, bonus, thx!

Comment: What would happen if, with the screen size example, the width is exactly 960px? Which CSS styling would it use, the "min-width" or "max-width"?